# Size of EventData array when azure function is input bound to azure event hub

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

Azure functions can be input bound to Azure Event Hub. When input binding is for EventData[] how is the size of the array determined? Is it all of the events in the Event Hub partition ?

Comment: this article helped me understand how messages are received: https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/in-order-event-processing-with-azure-functions-bb661eb55428

Comment: Thanks for sending the link. Even though it does not answer the question directly, provides great insights. Great article.

Answer (score 2):

It won't necessarily include all the events from a partition. The batch size is limited by the setting `maxBatchSize` that you can set in `hosts.json` file, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#hostjson-settings). The default value is `64`.

So, you can get any number of events up to max batch size. It's not guaranteed that you get exactly the same number. Sometimes it's going to be less depending on how many events are to be processed, the size of events and maybe other factors.